# Enabling TLS/SSL in elastic and logstash 7.1.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to connect logstash to elasticsearch-7.1.0 which has TLS/SSL
enabled using basic license. But every time when logstash tries to connect
to the elastic, "http client did not trust this server's certificate,
closing connection Netty4HttpChannel" warning is thrown by elastic.

I have generated certificates using both certutil and certgen but i think     both the certificates does not have the trusted author. how to generate a
certificate with trusted author?
Or it might be the scenario that in basic license version elasticsearch-7.1.0 can we use TLS/SSL for logstash?

```
My elasticsearch.yml 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: path/to/the/key/ca.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: path/to/the/cert/ca.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: [ 
"path/to/the/cert/ca.crt" ]

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificate 
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elastic-certificate
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
My logstash.yml
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeit
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]

xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.path:certs/elastic- 
certificate
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.truststore.password: password
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.path:certs/elastic- 
certificate
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.keystore.password: password
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
```

the warning i am getting is --" http client did not trust this server's     certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel"

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `ssl_certificate_verification => false` or path to CA cert `cacert => '/etc/elasticsearch/ca/key.pem'` into logstash configuration:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    ssl => true

    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    #or
    cacert => '/etc/elasticsearch/ca/key.pem'
    }
}
```